# Why button submit doesn't work if it isn't nested inside <form>?

Tags: html, forms, button, submit

Say I have this pretty simple code for picking a gender:

```
<form action="">
<p>Gender:</p>
<label for="male">Male</label>
<input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="man">
<label for="female">Female</label>
<input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="woman">

<button>submit</button>
</form>
```

It works flawless, just as desired. But I must play around. I tried removing `form tag`. So it now looks identical, just without `form tag`:

```
<p>Gender:</p>
<label for="male">Male</label>
<input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="man">
<label for="female">Female</label>
<input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="woman">

<button>submit</button>
```

After this change, my program is **broken**. I realized that it needs to be inside `form` to be **submitted**, so it knows which **data** to `submit`.

My question is why? Why 'tie' us to one `form`? What if I had like `10 forms` in my **program**. Does that mean I would have to have `10 forms` each with `submit button`? I guess I am missing something, as the design I 'put in my head' doesn't make much sense.

Comment: each form has it's own submit button.  If you want to use one submit button for multiple forms you would need to use javascript.

Comment: You can try using **attribute selectors** in CSS and this way you can use the same appearance and functionality between many buttons. But yes you will have to create multiple individual buttons and forms. But no you don't have to retype their settings and function over again. You can use the `class` or `id` attributes if you want to achieve the same result, as @K.Sharpe21 mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume you would specify each form and submit button with a class or an Id. Also did you try giving your submit button a type? such as:

```
<form id= "gender-form" action="/">
<button id="genderSubBtn" type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>

<form id= "age-form" action="/">
<button id="ageSubBtn" type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```